# Windows Subsystem for Linux - Mono and HTTP?

Tags: c#, bash, ubuntu, mono, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been playing around with bash (WSL) on Windows, and it seems that in general Mono is working pretty well except for web requests.

Things like:

- `nuget restore`
- Cake builds (they heavily rely on NuGet)
- `<DownloadUri>` MSBuild task

NuGet gives an error such as:

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request
  Error: ConnectFailure (Value does not fall within the expected range.)
  Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

The MSBuild `DownloadUri` task is a little more detailed:

```
~/Desktop/Git/xamarin-android-wsl/build-tools/android-toolchain/android-toolchain.targets: error : Unable to download URL `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r03.zip` to `~/android-archives/android-15_r03.zip`: An error occurred while sending the request
        ~/Desktop/Git/xamarin-android-wsl/build-tools/android-toolchain/android-toolchain.targets: error : An error occurred while sending the request  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00479] in <87f8b5c7f72e421da9517f7994c1c4a2>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__47.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <87f8b5c7f72e421da9517f7994c1c4a2>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<GetStreamAsync>d__50.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in <87f8b5c7f72e421da9517f7994c1c4a2>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <204f770036d441bb8dfd3daba3550e83>:0
  at Xamarin.Android.BuildTools.PrepTasks.DownloadUri+<DownloadFile>d__10.MoveNext () [0x00144] in <795d8966faf1420aa200f81c93259c0d>:0
```

This kind of throws a wrench into running automated builds for linux using WSL. It appears to be an issue with Mono on WSL, since it seems to be any .NET code that makes a web request. I would also mention that commands like `wget` or `curl` work just fine.

I'm running the latest Mono on the beta channel (although I had the same issues on stable):

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.2.0.215 (tarball Mon Aug  7 20:55:15 UTC 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

My Windows version:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise
Version: 1703
OS Build: 15063.502
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1639; this seems to be fixed in Windows Insider build 16215 ([also see WSL release history](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes)). For the non-insiders, the next stable release of Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update) is allegedly scheduled to be released on Oct 17.

Comment: BTW, I was able to get full stacktrace of `S.AE` from restore in `spew.log` with `msbuild /t:Restore /v:diag &> spew.log`; since mono 5.2+ is using msbuild15, and msbuild15 has [built-in restore capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#msbuild-integrated-restore) (which doesn't require nuget.exe presence on system anymore).